# Transfer files from windows to Kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, file-copy, windows-subsystem-for-linux

hello there I have set up a Linux virtual machine installed on my pc from Microsoft store up and running with windows also installed on the same pc. I cannot access files in the windows directory and copy them to the Kali Linux Graphical interface is there any way to overcome that?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of virtual machine? File transfer between host and guest systems are usually done by the virtual machine's mechanisms. There should be a way to define a shared folder (how VirtualBox is doing it), or just a special syntax to reach host's file system (WSL for example).

As alternative: you can have an external storage - upload/download file to NAS. Or even to some web-service if everything else does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You install the Linux virtual machine from Microsoft store.
I assume your Linux is WSL ( Windows Subsystem for Linux ).

If so, open File Explorer -> View -> Navigation Pane.
There should be a list at left side about all the sources you could access.

Click the "Linux" at Bottom.
You will see your Linux data there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cp` command to copy files from windows to Linux because windows-subsystem-for-linux mount automatically the `C` drive. You can check it from Linux with:

```
sudo ls /mnt/c/Users/username_here/
```

e,g: to copy `file.txt` from `/Documents` to your `/home` use:

```
sudo cp /mnt/c/Users/$Windows_USER/Documents/file.txt .
```